# Как вычленить массив со стороны сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js, клиент-сервер

Суть такая, мне нужно получить массив людей, зашедших на сервер(вводится имя прежде чем попасть на сайт). Реализовал очень плохо, на стороне клиента создаю массив и на стороне сервера такой же массив и они между друг другом передаются, но проблема в том, что массив созданный на стороне клиента заполняется только в запросах к серверу, то есть в локальной области видимости, мне же нужен доступ к нему глобально. Вот реализация:

Клиентская часть:

```
const userName = prompt("Введите свой никнейм:");
nameBlock.innerHTML = userName;

let arrayUser = []; // массив пользователей

socket.emit('connect user', {
    userConnect: userName, // передаем имя
    arrayConnect: arrayUser // передаем массив, куда записываем имена
});

socket.on('connect user', (userName) => {
    arrayUser.push(userName.arrayConnect);
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = `Пользователь <b><span class = "user">${userName.name}</span></b> подключился к чату!`
    userConnect.append(item);
})
```

Серверная часть:

```
let arrayUser = []; // так же создаем массив
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat message', {
            message: msg.message,
            name: msg.name
        });
    });

    socket.on('connect user', (userName) => {
        arrayUser.push(userName.userConnect);
        console.log(arrayUser);
        io.emit('connect user', {
            name: userName.userConnect,
            arrayConnect: arrayUser
        });
    });
```

Comment: Зачем вам массив на стороне клиента? Вы же можете его подменить. Это не безопасно. Гораздо проще хранить этот массив на стороне сервера и как только клиент заходит - отправляется событие серверу(+свое имя). Сервер добавляет имя в массив и рассылает всем клиентам новую информацию. Пользователи получив эту информацию обновляют данные у себя.

Comment: Я так тоже хотел сделать, хранить массив только на сервере, но как мне тогда это передать в socket.emit(отправляем запрос на сервер), вторым полем объекта у меня массив объектов, я могу туда просто пустышку отправить, а потом он заполнится?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так это должно выглядеть.
Клиент:

```
socket.on('state', (users) => {
    console.log(users) // массив всех пользователей пришедших с сервера
})

socket.emit('new user'); // уведомляем, что зашли как новый пользователь
```

Сервер:

```
let users = [];
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on("new user", function(){
        users[socket.id]['name'] = 'sdafasf' // тут можно получение имени сделать от пользователя как у вас
        io.sockets.emit('state', users);
    })
    
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){ // удаляем пользователя из массива
        delete users[socket.id]
        io.sockets.emit('state', users);
    })
});
```